# Como puedo hacer para ejecutar una función en cierto tiempo

Tags: c++, hilos, ogre

estoy programando en C++ y estoy haciendo uso del motor de renderizado Ogre 3D.
Necesito ejecutar una animación luego que pase 1 segundo antes que se ejecute la segunda animación, si hago un "for" o algo por tiempo, el motor de renderizado se detiene por esos segundos, es decir, mi intento de juego se detiene, creo que debo hacer hilos, pero no tengo experiencia con los mismos.

Actualmente tengo la siguiente lógica:

SI ANIMACIÓN 1 HA FINALIZADO
ACTIVO ANIMACIÓN 2

Estoy compilando con C++ 11

Necesito que pase 1 segundo para eso :(

Comment: Para poder ayudarte es necesario que muestres lo que llevas hecho y qué has intentado. Es complicado dar respuestas concretas si no conocemos el contexto de uso. Por ejemplo, estándares antiguos no tienen librería de hilos propia por lo que hay que recurrir a la API del SO o bien a librerías de terceros... y esa es solo la punta del iceberg. Si quieres respuestas tendrás que ampliar la información que proporcionas en la pregunta

Comment: C++ 11 (ya edite la pregunta). No quise copiar el codigo porque es simplemente un IF que pregunta si la animación 1 ha finalizado entonces empieza la 2. Y todo el código son mas de mil lineas. No entiendo que dato necesitos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De cuando usaba Ogre3D hay dos opciones:

- La "difícil" que es usando hilos, lo cual tendrías que aprender, y es crear un hilo para la ejecución de animaciones y que después de que acabe la animación ejecutar un usleep(1000).
- La "fácil" y rápida que es obtener deltaTime entre frames una vez acabe la animación 1, e ir sumándolo en una variable de la clase, y cuando éste sea >= 1 empezar la animación 2.

Por cierto, te aconsejo tener una clase que se encargue de gestionar las animaciones.

Me gustaría haberlo escrito como comentario, pero no tengo reputación suficiente.

Comment: a ver si ahora subis un poquito de reputación jaja, gracias :) voy a intentarlo. Me  gustaría hacer la opción 1 pero la 2 la veo mucho mas fácil.

Comment: Por cierto, Ogre3D ya esta obsoleto verdad? ya casi nadie lo usa?

Comment: Obsoleto para nada, al menos en cuestión de motor gráfico (se sigue usando para hacer visitas interactivas 3D a lugares). Y en videojuegos se ha usado para juegos como torchlight. Además leí hace un tiempo que en su roadmap tienen dar soporte a las nuevas APIs Vulkan y DX12, además de que hace no mucho salió una nueva versión de Ogre3D que aumentaba notablemente el rendimiento.

Comment: Lo que he notado es que su documentación es pesima, los foros casi nadie responde y ni hablar para integrar un motor de física, el wrapper que conozco "OgreBullet" da muchos problemas, ademas que parece que nunca fue terminado y ni hablar de su documentación, es escasa. Que motor se usa actualmente mas? (que haya soporte)

Comment: Para las físicas yo he usado Ogrebullet y no da problemas. El motor que se usa actualmente para qué? ¿Videojuegos? tienes unity, unreal, etc. Pero lo mejor es algo como Ogre3D, dado que te tienes que pelear con bastantes cosas, y eso luego se premia en el portfolio.